# Ubuntu 16.04. Recovery mode boot and failsafeX. How to access the console?

Tags: boot, command-line, 16.04, graphics, recovery-mode

I am trying to fix the installation vagaries following the [upgrade from 12.04 to 16.04 via 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812320/easy-upgrade-from-12-04-to-14-04-disgraceful-upgrade-onwards-to-16-04).

I am following the instruction of the post [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/a/218095/446253).

The greeter in my computer is OK. If I boot in recovery mode with **failsafeX** as suggested, the error message *the system is running in low-graphics mode* appears (just as it did after normal boot for good measure).

It is then suggested to access a terminal for a fresh install of the proprietary drivers (as seems to be relevant to this case of mine).

However, the key combination ALT+CTRL+F1 leads to a graphical interface where the system logs some progress data without the dialogue prompt.

If I hit ALT+CTRL+F2 I come back to the low-graphics warning dialogue, and that's pretty unresponsive.

If I hit ALT+CTRL and another function key, I am redirected to blank screens, thus again no login prompt.

Is there a way to have the login prompt and enter a terminal from within failsafeX environment? I am interested in solutions applicable to **Ubuntu 16.04**.

Comment: I faced the same issue and tried reverting with the older version too. Even tried apt-get update and upgrade. Yet that was not fixed. it got fixed after reinstalling the OS with 16:04. reattaining data drives as it is, seems like an  know issue with upgrade

Comment: @vembutech I have eventually found out that recovery mode was not quite needed to sort out the low graphics error. See [post if interested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819190/)